# Accordion Panel programmatically primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to make mega menu with accordion panel programmatically using primefaces, but how to do this?

Comment: did you ask for something like that http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/accordionPanel.xhtml

Comment: @YagamiLight this is not programatically i want making this using java coding

Comment: did you try to use `foreach` and mix it with the code that i made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give an answer about your question try to use this

I suppose that you have an entity that you call item and each item has a number of valuable informations ( the link title , xhtml path ...)

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="#{cart.items}">
 <p:panelMenu>

   <p:submenu label="#{item}" >
       <p:menuitem value="#{item.name}" outcome="/pages/" + #{item.pageName} + ".xhtml" icon="ui-icon-extlink" />
   </p:submenu>
 </p:panelMenu>

</c:forEach>
```

Hope that helped you

Comment: Afaik that is not programmatically but declarative

Comment: this is not programmatically.